# MongoDB: Why always report non-authorized error when try to manage users in one database?

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

all, I am new to mongoDB, and recently I am trying to set up a local env to try it, below is my step:

1. Use docker to create a mongoDB container:

   ```
   docker run -d -name my-mongo -p 27017:27017 \
     -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
     -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Asdf1234 \
   mongo:4
   ```
2. Then I use Studio 3T software to connect the admin database, and adds a new user named ***leon***, below is the role I granted:

[image: admin database users]

3. Then I create another database with the user ***leon*** :

[image: create a new data base]

4. Test the connection, the result is OK:

[image: Test connection of new database]

5. Connect to the new database, and right click on the Manage users menu:

[image: right click manage users menu]

6. But it always reports the non-authorized error:

[image: non authorized error]

Does anybody know the detail reason ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I assume user `leon` has been created twice. Once in database `admin` and once in database `tailchat`. Check all existing users with command `db.getSiblingDB('admin').getCollection('system.users').find({})`. See [Authentication Database](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-users/#authentication-database). Honestly, I am not aware of any reason why user should be created anywhere else than in `admin` (or `$external` in case of X.509 or LDAP authentication) database.

Comment: Try running the [connectionStatus](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/#connectionstatus) command to see which user and roles that connection currently uses.